# Is it uncommon for a party to win presidency, but lose house seats?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, congress, history

In the United States' 2020 Presidential election, it appears as if Joe Biden and the Democrats have won the presidency, however as of writing this, have lost 5 seats in the house, and will likely lose more once the rest of the votes are counted.

How common is it for this type of behaviour to happen when a president is defeated by an opposing party? I would assume that typically the senate/house roughly reflect the presidency.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not uncommon.  It happened in [2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_United_States_House_of_Representatives_elections), [2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_United_States_House_of_Representatives_elections), [1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992_United_States_House_of_Representatives_elections), and [1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988_United_States_House_of_Representatives_elections).

Comment: ie, the first election for Trump, George W. Bush, Bill Clinton, and George HW Bush, respectively. So every single new President in the last 32 years EXCEPT Obama.

Comment: One also wonders if at least some of this is not tactical voting:  don't like Trump, but worried about Dem proposals to pack Supreme Court.  Easiest way is then to vote pro-Biden, but pro Rep congress.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica yeah I definitely see the election as a vote for normalcy, to vote out Trump and his perceived behavioral problems, and the Democrats and their perceived embrace of far-left ideologies